# how to link Touchableopacity Youtube with TMDB API object?

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, video, youtube

I'm creating an app of movies/series Database and its almost done,there is a problem. I created a button that goes to youtube to see the trailer of movie but it doesn't work.

I tried two things but they didn't solve my problem:

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                  Linking.openURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${details.key.toString()}');
                }}
                >
```

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                  Linking.openURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${details.key}');
                }}
                >
```

{details.key} is the key of movie in youtube trailer,
any solutons please?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question with the error details.

Comment: It looks like you're using a single quote '. instead of a backtick ` around your `${details.key}` string. That could be the problem.

Comment: Linking.openURL(`  `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${details.key}` `); i used this but i still get video unvailable

Answer (score 0):

Use backtick instead of single quote and make sure details.key exist. Maybe something like:

```
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${details?.key}`
```

The question mark makes sure details data is fetched.

Comment: true, i found a problem in fetching data ` useEffect(() => {
    const getDetails = async () => {
      const data = await GET(`/movie/${props.route.params.movieId}`);
      setDetails(data);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    getDetails();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getVideo = async () => {
      const results = await GET(`/movie/${props.route.params.movieId}/videos`);
      setVideo(results);
      setLoading(false);
    };

    getVideo();
  }, []);`   is there any problem?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: not yet, i found that there is a problem in fetch data of videos , but i can't find a solution for it `useEffect(() => { const getDetails = async () => { const data = await GET(/movie/${props.route.params.movieId}); setDetails(data); setLoading(false); }; getDetails(); }, []);` `useEffect(() => { const getVideo = async () => { const results = await GET(/movie/${props.route.params.movieId}/videos); setVideo(results); setLoading(false); }; getVideo(); }, []); `